# Jira - Auto-Calculate Estimate based on story point

Tags: jira, agile

Is there a way within Jira that I can auto assign an Estimate value when I assign Story points to an issue?

As a business we get great use out of both - but I'm finding it slightly annoying to have to enter the data in multiple places.

Understood that Agile is less about actual time values - and Story points are best practice - but just wondering if there's a plugin or setting that would allow me to enter 20 Story points -for example- and that issue be assigned an 8hr Estimate automatically.

Comment: As far as I remember, when you set up the project to use story points, JIRA's Remaining Estimate and Time Spent fields are not used or updated automatically (Time tracking is set to none) because it is against most methodologies to estimate one way and track using both (creates a skew on estimation as you'd think on time when you ought to think about effort, etc.). Yet, as you said, you can set work logs adding time spent (but I'd bet it's more related to focus factor and other metrics)

Comment: @Alfabravo feel free to add your comment as the answer to this and I'll accept it. Seems like there's no way to carry out what I asked for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: I was asking this to my project manager, heh. Sorry we couldn't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, when you set up the project to use story points, JIRA's Remaining Estimate and Time Spent fields are not used or updated automatically (Time tracking is set to none)

[image]

because it is against most methodologies to estimate one way and track using both (creates a skew on estimation as you'd think on time when you ought to think about effort, etc.).

Yet, as you said, you can set work logs adding time spent (but I'd bet it's more related to focus factor and other metrics). I've done it for support-related tasks where a report might be generated later (but shouldn't be considered in a SCRUM sprint).